# Nusselt number for a rectangular fin under forced convention

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I am looking for the correct Nusselt Equation to calculate the heat transfer coefficient for a rectangular fin acted upon by air with a certain speed

Comment: What research have you done on this so far?

Comment: I got nusselt function for flat plates and other shapes but not for fins, or should I assume a rectangular fin to be a plate

Comment: Try this resource (it's excellent!): http://www.mie.uth.gr/labs/ltte/grk/pubs/ahtt.pdf

Comment: Thank you, but could not see the exact equation for Nusselt number for rectangular plate with straight fins

Comment: It might be under heat transfer from extended surface with variable heat transfer coefficient